# Text input doesn't go all the way up to end of input box

Tags: css, responsive-design

My input box is 40 pixels long, but when I start typing, the letters going go up to 20px before it stops and flows back in place as new letters are typed. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your input has `padding-right: 20px;` with `box-sizing: border-box` set on it.

Check out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jtL2r/1/)**